# Question about fetching Google Maps places

Tags: php, maps

My php site should shows to user a popup with a list of google maps places.
Ex: I search "Mc Donald's, New York" and I see a list of all Mc Donald's in New York.

But when a user select a place in that list, the system copy the place (longitude, latitude, name, street, city) in my database.

Is this possible?
And, when the next user search "Mc Donald's, New York" the list will show first my database results, and after the google maps results.

How can I do it?

I hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps - 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html